# How to obtain infra red / heat vision using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to achieve **infra red vision effect (the vision usually used for aliens in movies)**, just like the one used in **Predator 2**  - using OpenCV.

[image]

[image]

I have searched, but I have been pointed out that IR filter is made using webcam hardware that supports it.

Is there any way to achieve effect *close* to the above pictures using OpenCV? I am not sure myself what functionality to search for exactly. Need suggestions and guide from OpenCV / Image Processing Expertise. Thanks.

Comment: Please give reason for downvote!

Comment: I didn't downvoted but I think the concept of retrieving the infra-red image from the light spectrum is pretty much missed. As the name suggest infra-red is outside of the light spectrum so there is no way to retrieve such an information from the image.

Comment: Yes,  I don't know anything about such stuff. Hope for positive response from you people.. :)

Comment: If it you need it just for an effect you could try to convert an image to grayscale an then convert it to hsv by assigning the gray value to hue.

Comment: convert to grayscale, and apply a [colormap](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @David_D. Actually, I want to obtain such effect in which obstacles in environment will be pointing out.

Comment: @berak I will try. Thanks for your valuable suggestion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by **@Wojciech Frohmberg** in the comments, extracting infra red channel from light source (RGB) is not possible, unless you have a camera that can detect infra red rays exclusively. More information can be read from [this forum](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/extracting-infrared-channel-from-digital-rgb-image-td3256125.html) and [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared).

To achieve closest effect, I used [HSV ColorMap](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html) as pointed out by **@berak** in the comments, thanks to him.

```
cv::applyColorMap (InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int colormap)
```

**Effects:**

[image]

[image]

**Code:**

```
-(cv::Mat) convertIntoAlienVision:(cv::Mat)inputImage
{
    cv::Mat grayMat;

    if(inputImage.channels() == 1)
        grayMat = inputImage;
    else{
        grayMat = cv::Mat(inputImage.rows, inputImage.cols, CV_8UC3);
        cv::cvtColor(inputImage, grayMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    }

    cv::Mat coloredImage;
    cv::applyColorMap(grayMat, coloredImage, cv::COLORMAP_HSV);
    return coloredImage;
}
```